# How to make mdGridTile's into links

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a similar question as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612498/nesting-md-grid-tile-into-md-button-not-working-angular-material), but the answer doesn't seem to be listed anymore. I have a list of tiles that show a property image and some relevant information. I'd like each to be a full link to another page with more information on the property.

I've made my tiles into a directive, and currently the html content of that directive is wrapped in an anchor tag. Which works to reach my specified link, however that anchor tag only matches the height of the mdGridTileFooter.

Is there a way to make the entire tile clickable? So that the user can click on any part of it and access the intended link (not just the bottom footer?

The HTML Directive:

```
<a ng-click="spVm.linkToProperty(proforma)" ng-href="{{spVm.path}}">
<div>
<md-grid-tile-footer class="saved-prop-address">

  <div class="saved-prop-address-title" ng-bind="spVm.city"></div>

  <div class="saved-prop-address-subtitle" 
   ng-bind="proforma.listing.update_date | date: 'MMMM dd'"></div>

</md-grid-tile-footer>
</div>
</a>
```

The HTML Page with the Tile List:

```
      <md-grid-list md-cols-xs="2"
        md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-md="3" md-cols-gt-md="6"
        md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="4px">

        <md-grid-tile class="saved-prop"
        ng-repeat="proforma in sdVm.pageGroups[sdVm.saved.idx]"
        ng-click="sdVm.showSelectedProperty(proforma); sdVm.linkToProperty(proforma)"
        ng-href="{{sdVm.path}}"
        ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{proforma.thumbnail_url}})'}">

          <pgo-saved-property proforma="proforma">
          </pgo-saved-property>
        </md-grid-tile>

      </md-grid-list>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like the directive had no height, adding any responsive height/width styling to the anchor tag won't work.

Adding this code to the css for the directive, and the anchor tag, will bring the anchor/link to the full height and width of the tile.

```
style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%;"
```

And any responsive changes that occur with the tiles will work with this code as well.